# Interpreter written in Python not working properly

Tags: python, function, dictionary, interpreter

No, I'm not done with my interpreter questions yet. Sorry.

So I've written another interpreter for a programming language I made up in Python. The programming language has an interesting concept: you only get some basic commands. To "get" more complex commands, you have to write functions and combine the simple command given to you.

Anyways, I've written a simple interpreter for the language.

The problem is: the simple commands work, but defining functions doesn't.

Here's the interpreter (I've removed code that isn't useful for solving the problem).

```
class Interpreter:
    acc = 0
    defined = {}

    def read(self, cmd):
        tokens = cmd.replace("\n", ";").split(";")
        for token in tokens:
            self.parse(token)

    def parse(self, cmd):
        if cmd.startswith("def(") and cmd.endswith(")"):
            cmd = cmd[2:]
            cmd = cmd[:-1]
            cmd = cmd.split("|")
            self.defined[cmd[0]] = cmd[1]

        elif cmd in self.defined:
            self.read(self.defined[cmd])

        elif cmd == "1":
            self.acc += 1

        elif cmd == "2":
            print(self.acc)

        elif cmd == "i":
            self.acc = int(input(">> "))

i = Interpreter()
while 1:
    i.read(input("> "))
```

You can define functions using the syntax `def(name|code)`. For example, `def(cat|i;2)`.

Now, onto the problem I'm having. It's impossible to define functions. They just don't work. It doesn't throw an error or anything. It does nothing.

Here's the code I tried to use:

```
def(c|i;2)
c
```

It should get input and display it, but instead, it doesn't do anything.

This works, though:

```
i;2
```

It seems to me like the problem is somewhere in the `if cmd.startswith("def(")` if statement, because everything except the functions work.

Comment: Whats your working sample input? def( doesnt work at all

Comment: this `tokens = cmd.replace("\n", ";").split(";")` will split the def into two "tokens":  `def(c|i` and `2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving these kinds of problems it is imperative to be able to see what is going on while the program is running.  You can e.g. use a debugger or you can go with the age old debug print method (like I've done below).

I've extended the interpreter with a `p` command that prints the `acc`, and made it accept any integer, otherwise it is the same.

The problem you're having is that you destroy the input before you can store it in `defined`.  I solve it by only using `\n` to split outer commands and `;` to split commands inside a `def`.

```
import textwrap

class Interpreter:
    acc = 0
    defined = {}

    def read(self, cmd):
        cmd = textwrap.dedent(cmd).strip()
        lines = cmd.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            print '==> parsing:', line
            self.parse(line)

    def parse(self, cmd):
        if cmd.startswith("def(") and cmd.endswith(")"):
            print '::found def',
            name, code = cmd[4:-1].split('|')  # def( is 4 characters..
            self.defined[name] = code.replace(';', '\n')  # read() expects commands divided by \n, so replace ; before storing in self.defined
            print self.defined

        elif cmd in self.defined:
            print '::found defined name', cmd, '=>', `self.defined[cmd]`
            self.read(self.defined[cmd])

        elif cmd == "i":
            self.acc = int(input(">> "))

        elif cmd == "p":
            print(self.acc)

        else:
            self.acc += int(cmd)


intp = Interpreter()
intp.read("""
    def(c|i;2)
    c
    p
""")
```

the output from a run:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp> python pars.py
==> parsing: def(c|i;2)
::found def {'c': 'i\n2'}
==> parsing: c
::found defined name c => 'i\n2'
==> parsing: i
>> 5
==> parsing: 2
==> parsing: p
7
```

writing an interpreter that recursively calls itself in this way has some major limitations since every function call in the compiled language requires a function call in the host language (Python). A better way is to transform the program into a stack of commands, then pop a command from the stack and execute it. You're done when the stack is empty.  Function calls will then just involve pushing the value of the defined symbol onto the stack. I've extended your interpreter to do this below.  I've added a command `x0` which will exit a function call if `acc` is zero (and I push a `$marker` onto the stack before calling a function so I know where the function call started):

```
def debug(*args):
    pass
    # print '[dbg]', ' '.join(str(a) for a in args)

class Interpreter:
    acc = 0
    defined = {}
    commands = []  # the stack

    def compile(self, program):
        program = textwrap.dedent(program).strip()
        lines = program.split("\n")
        lines.reverse()
        self.commands += lines

        while self.commands:
            command = self.commands.pop()
            debug('==> running:', command, 'stack:', self.commands)
            self.run_command(command)

    def run_command(self, cmd):
        if cmd.startswith("def(") and cmd.endswith(")"):
            name, code = cmd[4:-1].split('|')
            self.defined[name] = code.split(';')
            debug('::found def', self.defined)

        elif cmd in self.defined:
            debug('::found defined name', cmd, '=>', `self.defined[cmd]`)
            # mark command stack before executing function
            self.commands += ['$marker']  
            self.commands += list(reversed(self.defined[cmd]))

        elif cmd == '$marker':
            pass  # do nothing (we get here if a def doesn't have an x0 when the acc is zero)

        elif cmd == 'x0':
            # exit function call if acc is zero
            if self.acc == 0:
                while self.commands:  # pop the stack until we get to the $marker
                    tmp = self.commands.pop()
                    if tmp == '$marker':
                        break

        elif cmd == "i":
            self.acc = int(input(">> "))

        elif cmd == "p":
            print(self.acc)

        else:
            self.acc += int(cmd)
```

we can now write recursive functions:

```
intp = Interpreter()
intp.compile("""
    4
    def(c|-1;x0;p;c)
    c
    p
""")
```

which outputs:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp> python pars.py  
3                                    
2                                    
1                                    
0
```

instead of an accumulator (`acc`) it is probably more expressive to use the stack for values too, so e.g. `5;p` would push `5` on the stack, then `p` would print the top element on the stack. Then you could implement addition like `5;2;+` meaning `push 5`, `push 2`, and let `+` mean `add top two items on stack and push the result`... I'll leave that as an excercise ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, program is working perfectly now :) Also, the reason I use an accumulator is because the programming language is supposed to be a bare-bones on that you can easily build upon using the `def()` command. I might look into implementing a stack though ;)